# Nuxt 3 generate static bundle without modules (like Nuxt 2)

Tags: nuxt3

We've started releasing our new project and it turned out that our platform requires to make an odr archive from our bundle and there will be no static hosting for it (as es6 modules requires), files  from odr will be saved on the user device and then run from it.
In other words, we have to create a bundle that could be runned only by opening index.html in the browser and all the dependencies will be loaded by file:// protocol
It seems to be pretty hard and unwelcome to downgrade from nuxt 3 to nuxt 2 and I know that nuxt 3 does not have a simple instrument for it, but maybe there is a some terrible way to trasform our bundle to make it working this way? (maybe configure webpack on nuxt3 somehow, transform to commonjs...)

generate nuxt 3 bundle and I wanna see index.html and its dependencies without module scripts

Comment: Suppose that I've found an issue https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/14507
And some proposal from nuxt dev https://github.com/danielroe/nuxt-full-static

Comment: We decided downgrade to nuxt 2 due to lack of options